# transforms.route.topic.expression and groovy expression

Tags: groovy, apache-kafka, debezium

I'm trying to use debezium transforms.route.topic.expression
Here the entries in connector configuration

```
"transforms": "dropPrefix,unwrapi,route",
"transforms.dropPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
"transforms.dropPrefix.regex": "rocketlawyer.dbo.(.*)",
"transforms.dropPrefix.replacement": "$1",
"transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
"transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
"transforms.route.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ContentBasedRouter",
"transforms.route.language": "jsr223.groovy",
"transforms.route.topic.expression": "value.snapshotequals('true') ? ${topic} : cdc.$1"
```

when I'm applying config call I'm getting following error

```
iguenkin_rocketlawyer_com@dbadm-r208:~/confluent$ curl -d  @mssql_trg_cf.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/mssql_trg/config | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1326  100   242  100  1084  30250   132k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  161k
{
  "error_code": 500,
  "message": "Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 1, column: 832]"
}
```

column: 832

"transforms.route.topic.expression": "value.snapshotequals('true') ? ${topic} : cdc.$1"

column 830 is a blank space in string `: cdc`

Here the questions

1. how can I be sure that jsr223.groovy is installed and accessible to transformations
   as I am understand it is a part of dibezium connector, so it is not listed as a separate plugin
   here the list of jars whee debezium is installed

`-rw-r--r-- 1 iguenkin_rocketlawyer_com 1234193955  20272 Dec  9 20:44 debezium-api-1.3.1.Final.jar

-rw-r--r-- 1 iguenkin_rocketlawyer_com 1234193955  91369 Dec  9 20:44 debezium-connector-sqlserver-1.3.1.Final.jar

-rw-r--r-- 1 iguenkin_rocketlawyer_com 1234193955 844500 Dec  9 20:44 debezium-core-1.3.1.Final.jar

-rw-r--r-- 1 iguenkin_rocketlawyer_com 1234193955  19090 Dec 15 22:01 debezium-scripting-1.3.1.Final.jar

-rw-r--r-- 1 iguenkin_rocketlawyer_com 1234193955 16839 Dec 16 01:04 groovy-jsr223-3.0.7-indy.jar`

2. if groovy is installed what is wrong with expression ? I've used following documentation to set connector https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/content-based-routing.html

Comment: From your link: Debezium does not come with any implementations of the JSR 223 API. So, you have to install js, groovy, or other implementation separately.

Comment: The error you have saying `Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34))` . First example in documentation gives format of config like this: `transforms=route` - without double quotes.. so, why do you have different format?

Comment: yes, here the jar I've put in the dibezium directory groovy-jsr223-3.0.7-indy.jar and regarding format I have not seen how to use *.property file in conjunction with curl